# C/C++ sscanf(): get pointer to text (if any) after the converted text

Tags: c, scanf

I swear I've done this 100 times in my career and thought `%s` did it, but I see that it doesn't.

Specifically I have

```
          iParsed = sscanf( pszValue, "%4d-%2d-%2d%c%2d:%2d:%f%s",
                        &stm.tm_year, &stm.tm_mon, &stm.tm_mday, &cSeparator,
                        &stm.tm_hour, &stm.tm_min, &dSec, &pcFollow );
```

`pcFollow` is a `const char*`.  I simply want to know what follows this date/time format, so that I can 1) check to see if an optional field is attached at that point, or 2) to complain about garbage in the string.  In other situations, I might want to 3) continue parsing at that point.

`%s` however wants a `char*`, not a `char**`.  It wants an actual character buffer to hold a copy of whatever is following the `%f` in my example.

The only idea I have is to use `%n` to capture number of characters parsed, and use that as an offset to `pszValue`.  In fact this would be fine except it's simply not how I remember doing it.

Comment: `%s` never did do what you seem to remember it doing. `%n` would be a reasonable way to do it.

Comment: Since `pcFollow` is already a pointer,  you don't need `&` before it. Instead of `"%s"` why not `" %[^\n]"`? `"%s"` will work, but will result in an *input failure* if nothing is there (and you can't rely on what is in `pcFollow` at that point). It will miss any whitespace separated values that follow the first after your `float`. `" %[^\n]"` will handle whitespace separate values -- but with the same *input failure* if nothing is there to read. ***check the return***.

Comment: Seriously dangerous advice David.  You seem to assume that pcFollow is actually pointing at sufficient storage for whatever follows, which it absolutely isn't.  To be fair, your other points are reasonable enough.

Comment: I guess that this is a C question. Can you please change the Tag?

Comment: How would you use `pcFollow` to store remaining input while it points to `const char`? Not to mention the extra `&`.

Comment: "How would you use pcFollow to store remaining input"  My recollection about how %s acted was faulty, as I explained.  I will not explain it again, but direct you to re-read the question.   @Gerhardh bitte lesen Sie die Frage, dann kommentieren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt your existing solution as follows:

1. As suggested in your question and the answer by @wilx, use format specifier `%n` and pass an additional `int` parameter to [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to capture the number of characters consumed (which will also be the index of any trailing data).
2. Rather than a <strike>`const`</strike>`char *`, pass the address of a single `char` to detect presence of trailing data.
3. Use the return value from [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to validate the number of items parsed (**7** would be appropriate for your use case); a smaller number would indicate a mid-parse failure, and a larger number would indicate trailing data.

Here is a working example (not covering all the edge cases but should be a starting point):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

static void parse_time(const char* pszValue, struct tm* pstm, int* piItemsParsed, int* piCharsConsumed, char* pcFollow)
{
    float dSec;
    char cSeparator;
    *piItemsParsed = sscanf( pszValue, "%4d-%2d-%2d%c%2d:%2d:%f%n%c",
                             &pstm->tm_year, &pstm->tm_mon, &pstm->tm_mday, &cSeparator,
                             &pstm->tm_hour, &pstm->tm_min, &dSec, piCharsConsumed, pcFollow );
    printf("Time String    = '%s'\n", pszValue);
    printf("Items Parsed   = %d\n", *piItemsParsed);
    printf("Chars Consumed = %d\n", *piCharsConsumed);
    printf("Char Following = 0x%02x\n", (unsigned int) *pcFollow);
}

static void report(const char* pszValue, int iItemsParsed, int iCharsConsumed)
{
    if (iItemsParsed == 7)
    {
        printf("Timestamp is valid\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Timestamp has trailing data: '%s'\n", pszValue + iCharsConsumed);
    }
}

static void parse_and_report(const char* pszValue, struct tm* pstm)
{
    int iItemsParsed;
    int iCharsConsumed;
    char cFollow;

    parse_time(pszValue, pstm, &iItemsParsed, &iCharsConsumed, &cFollow);
    report(pszValue, iItemsParsed, iCharsConsumed);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct tm stm;
    static const char pszValue[] = "2020-03-01 07:31:30.345";
    static const char pszValue2[] = "2020-03-01 07:31:30.345trailing data";
    static const char pszValue3[] = "2020-03-01 07:31:30.345 more trailing data";
    static const char pszValue4[] = "2020-03-01 07:31:30.345\nyet more trailing data";

    parse_and_report(pszValue, &stm);
    parse_and_report(pszValue2, &stm);
    parse_and_report(pszValue3, &stm);
    parse_and_report(pszValue4, &stm);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Time String    = '2020-03-01 07:31:30.345'
Items Parsed   = 7
Chars Consumed = 23
Char Following = 0x00
Timestamp is valid
Time String    = '2020-03-01 07:31:30.345trailing data'
Items Parsed   = 8
Chars Consumed = 23
Char Following = 0x74
Timestamp has trailing data: 'trailing data'
Time String    = '2020-03-01 07:31:30.345 more trailing data'
Items Parsed   = 8
Chars Consumed = 23
Char Following = 0x20
Timestamp has trailing data: ' more trailing data'
Time String    = '2020-03-01 07:31:30.345
yet more trailing data'
Items Parsed   = 8
Chars Consumed = 23
Char Following = 0x0a
Timestamp has trailing data: '
yet more trailing data'
```

Comment: Your answer #3 is what I was trying to recall doing in the past and couldn't think of, albeit mainly of use for my case #2 (detecting trailing garbage).  If "%*s" results in a higher args-matched return value, then there's something there.  If it doesn't match, then at most you have white space which in most circumstances I see, can be allowed.  Very thorough answer too--future generations will honor your name!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%n` format specifier. It fills an `int` variable with number of characters consumed so far: `"%4d-%2d-%2d%c%2d:%2d:%f%s%n"`